# Partial Pivoting In Pandas SQL Or Spark

Tags: python, pandas, scala, apache-spark, xlsx

Partial Pivoting In Pandas SQL Or Spark

Make the Year remain as Rows, and have the States Transpose to columns
Take Pecentage value of a Gender Male Race White,

**Input**

> [image: Blockquote]

**Output**

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Could you please post data as text, not images? Also, what code have you tried so far?

Comment: In pandas, try `df.pivot_table(index='Year', columns='States', values='Percentage')`

Comment: or `df.set_index(['Year', 'States'])['Percentage'].unstack()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer Posted By @Peter Leimbigler as comment

```
df.pivot_table(index='Year', columns='States', values='Percentage')
```

I tried it works.. Thanks Peter

Comment: Hey, that's great to hear!